# Comparing two passwords PHP

Tags: php

Here's my code it seems to work fine, how ever it doesn't look right.
I know I'm vulnerable to injections. Just want to know if the this 
is the best way of comparing two passwords ?

```
if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $errors[] = "Please enter a password";
} else {
    if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password1']) {
        $errors[] = "Your password did not match the confirmed password";
    } else {
        $p = $_POST['password'];
    }
}
```

Comment: The above code is not vulnerable to any injections, as it doesn't interact with a database or print user input to the screen. (code we can't see may be another story)

Comment: You can also try `!==`.

Comment: You *expect* them to always both be strings.  `!==` will *confirm* that they are both the same type, although you'd need a separate test to confirm that they are strings.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is fine, I would just write it a bit differently:

```
if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
   $errors[] = "Please enter a password";
} elseif($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password1']) {
   $errors[] = "Your password did not match the confirmed password";
} else {
   $p = $_POST['password'];
}
```

Comment: That's the answer I'm looking for I had two closing brackets at the end of the script just didn't look right.

Comment: @user1829823 your code was fine, just the indentation made it look weird. I nudged it around for you.

Comment: @Neal I didn't say yours was bad, just that OP's only "didn't look right" because of the indentation. Here, have a +1. :P

Comment: A request using this form would still end in matching passwords: `<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="password[0]" value="this" />
<input type="hidden" name="password[1]" value="that" />
<input type="hidden" name="password1[0]" value="this" />
<input type="hidden" name="password1[1]" value="that" />
<input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You must check both `$_POST['password']` and `$_POST['password1']` at very beginning.

```
if (!empty($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password1'])) {
        if (strcmp($_POST['password'], $_POST['password1']) === 0) {
            $p = $_POST['password'];
        } else {
            $errors[] = "Your password did not match the confirmed password";
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Please enter a password";
    }
```